# compare DDL with bash

Tags: bash, awk, comm

I need to compare two ddl, for the same table and identify the changes:

- new column
- deleted column
- datatype change

for example
DDL_1 is

```
column_1 int
column_2 char(10)
column_3 char(20)
```

DDL_2 is

```
column_1 int
column_3 char(40)
column_4 int
```

so:

> column_2 deleted
> column_4 added
> column_3 datatype change

and I need to obtain 3 files: `deleted`, `added`, `changed`

if I use
`comm -23 DDL_1 DDL_2 > deleted`
I would get column_2 (delete) but also column_3

`comm -13 DDL_1 DDL_2 > added`
I would get column_4 (add) but also column_3

how can I get the correct output?
many thanks
sergio

Answer (score 2):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'FNR==1  {split(FILENAME,f,"_"); prefix=f[1]}
       NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2; next} 
       $1 in a {if(a[$1]!=$2) print > (prefix"_changed"); 
                delete a[$1]; next} 
               {print > (prefix_"added")} 
           END {for(k in a) print k,a[k] > (prefix_"deleted")}' prefix_file1 prefix_file2

$ head added changed deleted
==> prefix_added <==
column_4 int

==> prefix_changed <==
column_3 char(40)

==> prefix_deleted <==
column_2 char(10)
```

Comment: cool! it is perfectly working. now I am defining the first part of the file names that need to be compared a variable, let's say ${A} so the awk command should be ran on ${A}_file1 ${A}_file2. and so I would like the output files, changed added and deleted to be called ${A}_changed, ${A}_added etc, etc but if I add the ${A} after print > "changed" for example, it doesnt work :( how could I overcome to this?

Comment: if I didn't make a typo, it should read the prefix from the first filename and use it in the generated filenames.

Comment: not sure if it does make any difference or not, but the the prefix is already a variable. what I mean is that the awk command should be run using: ${prefix}_file1.txt and ${prefix}_file2.txt. and I can't figure out why FNR==1  {split(FILENAME,f,"_"); prefix=f[1]} is not reading it :( basically before your awk command I am defining the prefix as prefix=$(echo $A | cut -d'/' -f3)